# Moved for work and had my salary cut

Tags: salary, canada

I was hired from the competition with big promises. I moved to a new province for this new company. They made me sign an agreement but never sent me a copy as promised. 2 months after I moved my whole family (house still in last province) they cut my pay by 25%. (all managers cut by 25%, but none of them moved for the company) Now they have merged with a new company and are offering me an entry level job and pay. It's close to 50% of what I was originally offered to move.

What are my options? Company based in Quebec, I moved to Ontario.

Comment: How did you sign the agreement without getting a copy to sign?

Comment: Canadian to Canadian - get a lawyer. If you had been employed by them for a long time, you could claim constructive dismissal and they would be on the hook for severance. In this case, you may have a claim against them because they hired you away from a good job, only to engage in constructive dismissal.

Answer (score 4):

In Canada if they are taking away your present job you are under no obligation to take the new one from them.  Under this circumstance you would likely qualify for special employment insurance benefits since you are looking at a drop of more than 40% of your weekly income.  The only catch here is whether your have enough hours to qualify.  I'm not sure if hours count nationally or provincially.  Talk to your local employment insurance office to see what they can do for you.  Odds are good you will make more by declining the entry level job and focusing on getting a job more in line with where you are in your career.

Comment: There doesn't seem much more that could be done than this, very unfortunate position to be in.